# Replace incorrect urls in text file and fix them in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, url

I'm getting URLS with removed forward-lashes and I basically need to correct the urls inside of a text file.

The URLs in the file look like this:

`https:www.ebay.co.ukitmReds-Challenge-184-214-Holo-Shiny-Rare-Pokemon-Card-SM-Unbroken-Bonds-Rare124315281970?hash=item1cf1c4aa32%3Ag%3AXBAAAOSwJGRfSGI1&LH_BIN=1`

I need to correct it to:

`https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Reds-Challenge-184-214-Holo-Shiny-Rare-Pokemon-Card-SM-Unbroken-Bonds-Rare/124315281970?hash=item1cf1c4aa32%3Ag%3AXBAAAOSwJGRfSGI1&LH_BIN=1`

So basically I need a regex or another way that will edit in those forwardslashes to each URL within the file and replace and the broken URLs in the file.

Comment: Do the URLs follow any particular pattern? For example if we had "http:example.comabcd", how would we know if it's "http://example.com/abcd" or "http://example.com/a/b/c/d"? If your URLs do follow a pattern, it might be good to include a few of them so people can see the pattern.

Comment: The pattern is just a standard eBay item URL.

All of them are the same http://ebay.co.uk/itm/item-name/itemnumber?hash=itemhash

Comment: Have you tried anything out yet and had problems? It can help to add examples of what you've tried so we can try and help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    import time
    import re
    #input file
    fin = open("ebay2.csv", "rt")
    #output file to write the result to
    fout = open("out.txt", "wt")


    #for each line in the input file
    for line in fin:
        #read replace the string and write to output file
        fout.write(line.replace('https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/', 'https://').replace('itm', '/itm/').replace('https:www.ebay','https://www.ebay'))

    with open('out.txt') as f:
      regex = r"\d{12}"
      subst = "/\\g<0>"
      for l in f:
          result = re.sub(regex, subst, l, 0, re.MULTILINE)
          if result:
              print(result)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I eventually came up with this. It's a bit clumsy but it does the job fast enough.